# error getting or saving values from formatted text feld to access database

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, jformattedtextfield

I have created an access database and in it I have field with variable currency.

Then on my form I have added FormattedTextField, and I am using the following code to save data into my database.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String tDate = transDate.getText();
    String rCash = reportCash.getText();
    String sCash = sideCash.getText();
    String poCash = paidOutCash.getText();
    String hPlus = hotelPlus.getText();
    String tDrop = totalDrop.getText();

    try
    {
        rs.moveToInsertRow();
        rs.updateString("TransDate", tDate);
        rs.updateDouble("ReportCash", rCash);
        rs.updateDouble("SideCash", sCash);
        rs.updateDouble("PaidOutCash", poCash);
        rs.updateDouble("HotelPlus", hPlus);
        rs.updateDouble("DropAmount", tDrop);
        rs.insertRow();
        st.close();
        rs.close();

        st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "select * from monthlyReport";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        rs.next();

    }catch(Exception ex) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex); }
}
```

But I am getting error at:

```
rs.updateDouble("ReportCash", rCash);
rs.updateDouble("SideCash", sCash);
rs.updateDouble("PaidOutCash", poCash);
rs.updateDouble("HotelPlus", hPlus);
rs.updateDouble("DropAmount", tDrop);
```

the error is :

no suitable method found for updateDouble(String,String)
method ResultSet.updateDouble(int,double) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to int)
method ResultSet.updateDouble(String,double) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to double)

Can anyone please explain the problem to me and suggest what I should do.

Thanks

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong. You're trying to pass a `String` to a method that takes a `double`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change these:

```
String rCash = reportCash.getText();
String sCash = sideCash.getText();
String poCash = paidOutCash.getText();
String hPlus = hotelPlus.getText();
String tDrop = totalDrop.getText();
```

They're all formatted as String, you need to change those to Number:

```
Number rCash = reportCash.getText();
Number sCash = sideCash.getText();
Number poCash = paidOutCash.getText();
Number hPlus = hotelPlus.getText();
Number tDrop = totalDrop.getText();
```